# tomcat startup java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [Ljava.lang.String;

Tags: java, tomcat, startup

This is the error i am getting when starting tomcat for only a specific application.

I used to work with the same application before my system is formatted.

Can anyone please explain me the cause for this exception.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [Ljava.lang.String;
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:635)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:422)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:348)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3795)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
```

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: Has your `JAVA_HOME` changed?

Comment: yes previously it was pointed to 1.5 now its pointed to 1.6.... wat difference does this make???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your JDK/JRE version and your Tomcat app version donot match.

1. You can try to change back to the origin JDK/JRE that works.
2. or just try this 
   -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true

Comment: ok now when i pointed to 1.5 its working... but with tomcat 6 JAVA_HOME set to 1.6 should also work... but its not..!!!

Comment: @neohope Why would that cause a problem? Java binaries are backwards-compatible.